# Como trazer um resultado do BD com NODE.js para dentro de uma array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Pessoal como faço para amazenar, dados que estão no banco de dados, em um array, com NODE.js?

Eu tenho esse valor esse valores no banco de dados:

Coluna 1

```
(linha 1)Fortaleza – Caucaia |(linha 2)
Fortaleza – Maracanau
```

Coluna 2

```
1(custo da viagem(linha 1)) | 6(tempo da viagem(linha 2))
```

E estou puxando do BD com esse codigo o resultado com o node.js:

bd_select.js

```
        var mysql = require('mysql');

        var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "",
        database: "bd_pops"
        });

        con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        con.query("SELECT * FROM tb_pops", function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
        });
        });
```

Então quero armazenar esses dados, de cada coluna, dentro dos arrays, que ficam dentro do script do arquivo modelo.html, que é rota[] e metrica[]. Alguem pode ajudar?

Comment: O `result` já é o próprio objeto que vc espera. Mas essa "estrutura" que vc tentou explicar na pergunta tá bem confusa! Aliás, percebi que você copiou [este exemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_select.asp). Só conferir o console demonstrado que vai entender. Aliás, `result` é um **objeto**, não especificamente um **objeto da classe Array**.

Comment: Sim copiei e adaptei. Mas quando puxo ele do BD ele aparece o resultado no console. E a primeira vez que estou usando o node.js! Mas obg pela orientação sobre o result.

Answer (score 1):

Veja se isso te ajuda:

```
var rota = [];
var metrica = [];
result.map(function(item){
    rota.push(item.NomeColuna1);
    metrica.push(item.NomeColuna2);
});
```

Comment: Eu colocaria isso depois do con.connect?

Comment: Coloca no lugar do console.log(result);

Comment: Cara deu certo em parte. Ele está repetindo os dados várias e várias vezes e criando array dentro de array.

Comment: Ok! Posta o código modificado por favor. Assim eu consigo te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Cara, vou coloca o codigo aqui:
`var mysql = require('mysql');
 var con = mysql.createConnection({
 host: "localhost",
 user: "root",
 password: "",
 database: "bd_pops"
 });
 var rota = [];
 var metrica = [];
 
con.connect(function(err) {
 if (err) throw err;
Con.query("SELECT * FROM tb_pops", function (err, result, fields) 
if (err) throw err;
result.map(function(item){
rota.push(item.pop);
console.log(rota);
});});});`

Comment: O resultado é esse: 
`[ 'POA' ]
[ 'POA', 'BEL' ]
[ 'POA', 'BEL', 'BLU' ]
[ 'POA', 'BEL', 'BLU', 'FLO' ]
[ 'POA', 'BEL', 'BLU', 'FLO', 'CUR' ]
[ 'POA', 'BEL', 'BLU', 'FLO', 'CUR', 'LON' ]
[ 'POA', 'BEL', 'BLU', 'FLO', 'CUR', 'LON', 'SPO' ]
[ 'POA', 'BEL', 'BLU', 'FLO', 'CUR', 'LON', 'SPO', 'SJC' ]
[ 'POA', 'BEL', 'BLU', 'FLO', 'CUR', 'LON', 'SPO', 'SJC', 'RJO' ]
[ 'POA', 'BEL', 'BLU', 'FLO', 'CUR', 'LON', 'SPO', 'SJC', 'RJO', 'BHO' ]
[ 'POA',
  'BEL',
  'BLU',
  'FLO',
  'CUR',
  'LON',
  'SPO',
  'SJC',
  'RJO',
'BHO',
'CAM' ]`

Comment: Só existe no banco de dados, referente a essa tabela, 20 itens.

Comment: var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({ host: "localhost", user: "root", password: "", database: "bd_pops" });
var rota = [];
var metrica = [];
con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    Con.query("SELECT * FROM tb_pops", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        result.map(function (item) { 
            rota.push(item.pop); 
        });

        console.log(rota); 
    });
});

Comment: Então, coloquei o código ajustado ai encima, o console.log(rota), estava dentro do looping, e tinha um erro de fechamento de { } também. Agora deve mostrar o resultado correto. Desculpe a demora.